# I want to add a function in a println

Tags: java

I'm trying to add the name input by the user into a printline in Java

```
 System.out.printf("According to your survey, an average of %.2f people rode the per day.",  media );
```

I want to add it at the part of the text "rode the..."

Comment: `System.out.printf("According to your survey, an average of %.2f people rode the %s per day.", media, "hamster");`???

Comment: Don't conflate two problems.  The problems are 1) get a string from the user, and 2) include a string into `printf` output.  If you treat the two problems as separate, they are easier to solve ... separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float media = 1.5f;
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.printf("According to your survey, an average of %.2f people rode the %s per day.",
                  media,
                  stdin.nextLine());
```

When you run the above code, you won't see anything printed until you enter a value and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If, for example, you enter Jabberwocky<sup>1</sup> then the following line will be displayed:

```
According to your survey, an average of 1.50 people rode the Jabberwocky per day.
```

<sup>1</sup>[Jabberwocky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky)

Answer (score 0):

Get user input First . then add into print line

```
String input = input.next();
 System.out.printf("According to your survey, an average of %.2f people" +input +  " rode the per day.",  media );
```